# How do I spawn independent children and re-establish communication in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

First the code:

---

test.js:

```
var cluster = require("cluster");

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    var app = cluster.fork();

    app.on("message", function(code) {
        console.log("Parent received: " + code);
        app.send("this is from the test.js parent");
        });
    }
else {
    process.send("");
    process.on("message", function(code) {
        console.log("Child received: " + code);
        process.send("this is from the test.js child");
        require("./testobj.js");
        process.exit(0);
        });
    }
```

---

testobj.js:

```
process.send("this is from testobj.js");

process.on("message", function(code) {
    console.log("testobj.js received: " + code);
    });

process.send("this is the second message from testobj.js");

while (true) {}
```

The result when running node test.js

```
Parent received: 
Child received: this is from the test.js parent
Parent received: this is from the test.js child
Parent received: this is from testobj.js
Parent received: this is the second message from testobj.js
```

---

Now that you see my work so far, the goal is to spawn sub processes independent of the parent but still retain two-way communications. The test code so far retains child to parent communication, but not parent to child. 
Does anyone have any suggestions on how to retain or re-establish parent to child communication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `while(true){}` is freezing that child's event loop permanently, though the `process.exit(0)` is killing the forked worker and making it no so permanent. As far as I know, you cannot exit a process and retain communication (since the process is no longer running essentially).

You should be able to more easily see what is transpiring by adding some more event listeners. The [fork](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_event_fork) event has a decent example, though it would be on your `app` variable instead of the referenced `cluster` variable.

```
app.on('fork', function(worker) {
  console.log('Worker forked: ' + worker.id);
  console.log(worker);
});
app.on('listening', function(worker, address) {
  console.log('Worker listening: ' + worker.id);
  console.log(address);
});
app.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
  console.log('Worker exited: ' + worker.id);
  console.log('Code: ' + code + ' Signal: ' + signal);
});
```

Based on the [worker.send](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_worker_send_message_sendhandle) documentation / example, it seems it might be a good idea to use an `else if(cluster.isWorker)` instead of just `else` per the example:

```
if (cluster.isMaster) {
  var worker = cluster.fork();
  worker.send('hi there');
} else if (cluster.isWorker) {
  process.on('message', function(msg) {
    process.send(msg);
  });
}
```